# How to navigate to a frame from different thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have to navigate to a page which belongs to the main window from a different thread. I created a separate thread to listen to command line arguments of another process. When I receive "about" from that process through IPC in the thread, I need to open `about.xaml` from the thread. How can I do it?

This is how I open the page from main window:

```
_mainFrame.Source = new System.Uri("AboutPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

How can I do the same from different thread ?

Comment: wpf? still too broad.. what have you tried or where do you stuck?

Comment: I think you're using `WPF` , please add the `WPF` tag and add some code

Comment: yes WPF.  _mainFrame.Source = new System.Uri("AboutPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative); This is how I open the page from mainwindow. How can I do the same from different thread.

Comment: Do you have errors? You can search for error message to get answer within seconds. From different thread you have to *invoke* into UI thread, by using [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx). This is then basically a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1284017/1997232) question.

Comment: thanks! answer of that question is working perfectly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the dispatcher to send actions to the UI thread.

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(()=>
{
        _mainFrame.Source = new System.Uri("AboutPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative); 
});
```