# Change ui value from code behind in task\thread

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In wpf Suppose I have a counter label, in code behind I tried to increment the value every 3 seconds but it doesn't work, I mean something like:

**XAML:**

```
<Label x:Name="MyLabel" Content="Label" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
public MyClass()
{
 Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                MyLabel.Content=i;
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                i++;
            }
        });
}
```

Output: the label stays the same

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1284120/6546734)

Comment: Just use MVVM. Write a viewmodel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, bind a property of the viewmodel to MyLabel.Content, and set the property in the thread. That's how WPF is designed to be used. You're discovering how painful it can be to fight against it. It only gets worse from here.

Comment: plz post answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF UIElement can only be accessed in a single Thread. So you cannot access or modify the value of the `<Label/>`.

But WPF also provides a thread model named `Dispatcher`, you can get the `Dispatcher` of the UIElement and invoke your action into the original thread.

What you should do is to change `MyLabel.Content=i` into `MyLabel.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MyLabel.Content = i);`.

This is the whole code:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    int i = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        // Note: this works because the thread slept 3000ms.
        // If the thread doesn't sleep, we should declare a new variable
        // so that i will not change when the action invokes.
        // That means `var content = i;`
        // Then `MyLabel.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MyLabel.Content = content);`
        await MyLabel.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MyLabel.Content = i);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        i++;
    }
});
```

I change your synchronized call to async call and this is recommended.

---

You'll find that `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` is very useful when you're trying to update UI in the background thread. Furthermore, you can add `DispatcherPriority` parameter to determine the running priority of all the actions you invoked.

Comment: I like this; I would recommend using ```Task.Run(async ()..await MyLabel.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync...await Task.Delay(3000)``` just to follow the Task await async signature.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I agree, and I've followed your idea. Thanks.